# Binding TextBlock inlines created outside UI thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mvvm, textblock

I've created a dependency property to allow a `TextBlock` to bind to `Inlines`, which works just fine.

Because my inlines creation is quite heavy I want to do it in a thread separate from the UI thread so that the UI doesn't hang when loading this particular content. However, when I create the inlines in a separate thread, I'm getting an `InvalidOperationException`

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

I then made some changes to the dependency property so that I use Dispatcher.Invoke on the object owned by a different thread. However, I then get a `TaskCanceledException`

> A task was canceled.

So, how can I use inlines in a `TextBlock` when the inlines have been created by a separate thread?

A minimum, complete and verifiable example is a bit big to post in this question (MVVM and all), but [**this file**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0Tb9IAMpQUhbV9OX25rcEhqaG8/view?usp=sharing) is a complete Visual Studio solution that will throw the first exception.

Both referenced exceptions happen in the dependency property (TextblockInlineBinding.cs), and this is the `PropertyChanged` from that file:

```
private static void OnInlinesPropertyChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
    var textBlock = obj as TextBlock;
    if (textBlock != null)
    {
        textBlock.Inlines.Clear();
        List<Inline> inlines = e.NewValue as List<Inline>;

        if (inlines != null) {
            // InvalidOperationException is thrown here
            textBlock.Inlines.AddRange(inlines);
        }
    }
}
```

Changing the `Inlines.AddRange()` line to use the inline's dispatcher, like this, causes the TaskCancelledException

```
foreach (Inline inline in inlines) {
    // TaskCanceledException is thrown here
    inline.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
        textBlock.Inlines.Add(inline);
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code where the exception is thrown? The second one.

Comment: @NtFreX Question now updated with more code and descriptions.

Comment: Inlines aren't Freezable, so you can't create them in another thread than the UI thread. Your approach won't work.

Comment: @Clemens If they can only be created in the UI thread, then how can one solve the problem of TextBlocks containing many inlines, including many images that are fetched online... this will be very slow and will cause the UI to hang, and will not be very userfriendly. Imagine loading a PDF and having the reader hang for 1 minute while it draws everything. Certainly there's gotta be a better way?

Comment: No idea, sorry. I don't think a component like a PDF viewer or a web browser would use a TextBlock with inlines.

Comment: @Clemens Do you happen to know of some alternatives? Say you want to create a Twitter client (*wink*). How would you display 30-40 tweets where each tweet needs to have clickable hashtags, usernames and URLs, as well as emoji images?

Comment: About how many inlines are we actually talking? 30-40 tweets doesn't sound like several thousands. Creating a few hundred of them in the UI thread should be a piece of cake. You may perhaps create a single tweet as an item in an ItemsControl, with a distinct TextBlock in the ItemTemplate.

Comment: @Clemens After having timed how long it takes to generate each tweet the tweets take about 1.6 seconds to generate, so either rendering this takes a long time, or there's something else going on. I'd really appreciate any help you can get, but I feel it would be wrong to discuss it here. Feel free to contact me on the email found on my Github account (link in profile) and I can fill you in completely.

Comment: Do these 1.6 seconds include the time it takes to make the Twitter API calls? If so, it may make sense to do all these calls asynchronously, in a separate thread, before converting the results to an Inline collection.

Comment: @Clemens No, they don't include the API calls. The API calls are already async in separate threads.

Comment: _"A minimum, complete and verifiable example is a bit big to post in this question"_ -- no, it's not. People post MVVM examples to Stack Overflow all the time. Maybe you're confused by the **minimal** requirement; you don't need to show _all_ of your code. Just the minimum required to illustrate your scenario. In the meantime, since `Inline` isn't freezable you need to create them in the UI thread as usual. You may be able to break the work up though, so that the user experience is still fine. Fix your question so there's a [mcve].